# How to fix "CondaValueError: Invalid environment name" in conda terminal when I use "conda env export"?

Tags: anaconda, conda

I want to export my conda environment by using `conda env export > xxx.yml`,but it doesn't work.

My conda environment is created by specify the `--prefix`, it names "E:/Envs/DRF".To export it, I use `conda activate E:/Envs/DRF` make it activated.And then I use `conda env export > xxx.yml`,it doesn't work and I get some Error below.

Firstly,activate it:

```
E:\WorkSpace\PyCharm\CET6Cat>conda activate E:/Envs/DRF
```

And then I wanna export it to .yml file:

```
(E:\Envs\DRF) E:\WorkSpace\PyCharm\CET6Cat>conda env export > environment.yml
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future r
elease.
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future r
elease.

CondaValueError: Invalid environment name: 'E:\Envs\DRF'
  Characters not allowed: ('/', ' ', ':')
```

It doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things you can try:

- Open conda prompt as admin. Run `conda update conda`. Restart prompt.
- You are using different path separators `/` and `\`. Use one of them. Also the error points out the usage of invalid characters. You should fix that.

Also, afaik `conda activate DRF` should have worked.

Here is what I was able to run on my windows system:

- Activating a env: `activate myenv`
- Exporting: `conda env export > myenv.yml`

Alternatively, you can export an environment without activating it. For that, you can use: `conda env export --name myenv > myenv.yml`

Also, you have used absolute paths. You can just use the environment names.
For checking the exact names of environments use: `conda env list`

Comment: Thank you but it still doesn't work. My conda is at the latest version and my OS is win7.It doesn't recognize my environment when I use `conda activate DRF`.I tried to use another slash(I've tried both '\' and '\') and then get the same error. I remember there was no such error a few months ago(at that time, I exported the `.yml` file in exactly the same way). Is this a bug in the new version of conda?

Comment: I find that my environment has no name, so I still get the same error when using `conda env export --name E:/Envs/DRF > xxx.yml`, but your latest edit gives me inspiration.I finally succeeded in using `conda env export --prefix E:/Envs/DRF > xxx.yml`!Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 19):

Try

```
conda env export --prefix /home/..../tfpy37 > dependency.yml
```

Here `tfpy37` is my *conda environment* name located in my ubuntu directory  `/home/...`.

Comment: This is the actual answer.